# “Illegal Choice has been detected”

Tags: 7, forms

I want to prevent validation check on the field_abc ?

How can I prevent validation for a field_abc

```
  function test_mail_menu() {
         $items['test-mail-1'] = array(
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguments' => array('test_mail1_form'),
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
            'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          );

    return $items;
    }
    function test_mail1_form ($form,$form_state) {
      $form = array();
      $form['field_abc'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('ABC'),
        '#validated' => TRUE,
     );

      $form['submit-button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#title' => t('sub'),
      );


      $form['#submit'][] = 'test_mail1_submit';
      $form['#validate'][] = 'test_mail1_validate';
      return $form;
    }

    function test_mail1_submit($form,&$form_submit) {



    }

    function test_mail1_validate($form, &$form_state) {



      if (!(is_numeric($form_state['input']['field_abc']))) {

        form_set_error('field_abc','ERROR');

      }
    }
```

Comment: why do you have submit-button and submit?

Comment: I just have single submit button. I have not written anything inside of submit function as of now .

Comment: $form['submit-button'], and $form['submit'] why do you have these two?

Comment: Yes, that $form['submit'] looks like a culprit. I'd remove it before proceeding.

Comment: I just wanted to check if on submit whether I get errors as I have used '#validation => TRUE' code to remove validation for that field(field_abc)

Comment: @Alfred Armstrong are you referring to $form['#submit'] or $form['submit-button'] ?

Comment: Neither, but this:  $form['submit']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array();

Comment: ok. will remove it and check whether it has caused the problem,

Comment: I have removed it but still it gives error where it should override validation #validation => TRUE ?

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why does no one mention that `'#validated' => TRUE`  is not a valid option for `textfield` according to [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#textfield)? Also setting `#validated => TRUE` doesn't "remove" validation for that field. If you don't want to validate a field, then just don't validate it. Simples.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to validate that field, then remove the following function

```
function test_mail1_validate($form, &$form_state) {



  if (!(is_numeric($form_state['input']['field_abc']))) {

    form_set_error('field_abc','ERROR');

  }
}
```

And remove the following line from `test_mail1_form`

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'test_mail1_validate';
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking for validation. If so please use this code, else explain your question clearly

```
function test_mail1_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();
      $form['field_abc'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('ABC'),
     );

      $form['submit-button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('sub'),
      );


      $form['#submit'][] = 'test_mail1_submit';
  return $form;
}

function test_mail1_submit($form, &$form_state) {
print_r($form);
exit;
}
```

Comment: please check the updated question .

Comment: Please check the Updated reply.